# Elasticsearch API and setting ID in child class

Tags: java, elasticsearch, inheritance, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a `Document` class that our library uses.  It's not annotated with anything so, when I try and persist it into Elastic the `_id` is being auto-generated and the `id` field gets included into the document, which is not correct - **it should not contain an `id` field**.

I need to update the project so that we can control the value that goes into the `_id` field, HOWEVER, I still need to use our `Document` class.

I figured I'd create an `ElasticDocument` class and have it `extend` from the `Document` class and simply @Override the `id` field and annotate it with `@id`.

```
public class Document {
    private String id;
    ...
    ...
}
```

```
// Cannot annotate with @Document since index is determined at runtime
public class ElasticDocument extends Document {
    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I try and persist my new `ElasticDocument` I am getting an error b/c both `ElasticDocument` and `Document` have an `id` field.

What's the best approach to allow us to save the `_id` field without creating a `id`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around the issue by continuing to use our `Document` class, but implemented a custom `BeforeConvertCallback<Document>` class that sets the `entity`'s `id` to null before persisting to Elastic.  This ensures that the request to index has the ID already set, but it's removed from the entity passed into the `Request`